# Resolve a multiTenant Service outside asp.net core pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, multi-tenant, saaskit

Our project is using multitenancy to resolve some Service, lets say `MyService` based on [SaasKit](https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit).

We also have a background task, which shares some of it's dependencies with the asp.net core controllers.

In the background task, any object that depends on `MyService` will get a null reference.

I can implement workarounds to get instances of `MyService`, like using service locator pattern, but this approach fails to create classes that depend on `MyService` without breaking DI and IOC logic.

So the question is: How can I get the same services that I can get from `HttpContext` with multitenancy, but get them without an `HttpCoontext`?

Comment: Can you show some code to better explain what it is you are asking in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is `MyService` and how did you decide the tenancy in the background. When there is not request from client, the backgound will fail to access the HttpContext which is not exist while there is no request. For a workaround, you may try to create a task table which contains `TenantId`, and then run the task from background.

Comment: I actually need to give much more details and code. Will do that in a day or two

Comment: @Alireza: Having the same issue. How did you resolve this issue ?